# Anyone translate a X12 271 Healthcare response

Tags: c#, edi, x12

I'm looking for C# code that translates a 271 health care eligibility benefit response to a more usable format so I can display certain segments and values into a datagridview. I'm looking for code that I can use to break this thing apart as it's not really difficult, just very tedious and was wondering if anybody else has done this and is willing to share.

Thanks!!

Comment: Got a link to the X12 271 spec? Also, there might be something here: http://www.openhre.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an open source X12 parser (OopFactory X12 Parser: https://x12parser.codeplex.com) that does this for you.

To convert any X12 document to Xml:

```
FileStream fstream = new FileStream("Sample1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var parser = new X12Parser();
Interchange interchange = parser.Parse(fstream);
string xml = interchange.Serialize();
```

To convert any X12 document to Html:

```
var htmlService = new X12HtmlTransformationService(new X12EdiParsingService(suppressComments: false));
Stream ediFile = new FileStream("Sample.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
string html = htmlService.Transform(new StreamReader(ediFile).ReadToEnd());
```

More details here: https://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parsing%20an%20837%20Transaction&referringTitle=Documentation

To load an X12 271 response into a .Net object, you can use:

```
FileStream fstream = new FileStream("Sample1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var service = new EligibilityTransformationService();
EligibilityBenefitDocument eligibilityBenefitDocument = service.Transform271ToBenefitResponse(fstream);
```

Answer (score 0):

DataDirect Technologies sells a [converter](http://www.xmlconverters.com/standards/hipaa) that will translate it into XML.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend perl or python for protoyping.  once you have behavior you want, you can:

- compile the whole thing
- have a programmer write C(whatever flavor you need) for the parts that are too slow.
- use the prototype as the spec for development in whatever language you need.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question.